# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at window.onload

Tags: javascript, php

I am using Tiny Editor to enter the product descriptions. And in database my datatype is BLOB. I am using Tiny Editor everywhere in my site and with same datatype BLOB, like in creating Blogs. It is working perfectly fine everywhere.

But i have a function to create food item. At first its datatype was varchar which was printing HTML TAGS while fetching. I fixed that too, but then again a strange issue came up. when i was entering a space between 2 paragraphs while entering a product, it was showing a random character "rn" in front end while fetching.

Then i changed the dataype of food description column as BLOB also as it was working for others. But then i encountered this issue

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input  at JSON.parse ()  at window.onload"

and my food items stopped getting displayed.

Here is my JS

```
<script>

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var categories = JSON.parse('<?php echo stripslashes(json_encode($categories)); ?>');
        
        window.merchantDetailsVueApp = new Vue({
            el   : "#vueApp",
            data : function()
            {
                return {
                    categories : categories,
                    filteredCategories : categories,
                    cart       : {
                        merchant : {
                            id : "<?php echo $merchantId; ?>"
                        },
                        items    : []
                    },
                    userId     : "<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : ''; ?>",
                    merchant   : null,
                    searchFood : "",
                };
            },
            computed : {
                shippingMethods : function()
                {
                    var methods = [];

                    if ("<?php echo $meta_data["delivery_option"]; ?>" === "Both")
                    {
                        methods.push("Delivery", "Pickup");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        methods.push("<?php echo $meta_data["delivery_option"]; ?>");
                    }
                    
                    
                    return methods;
                }
            },
            methods : {
                updateCartInLocalStorage : function()
                {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(this.cart));
                },
                updateCartFromStorage : function()
                {
                    this.cart = window.localStorage.getItem("cart") ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("cart")) : null;
                },
                onAddToCartButtonClick : function(foodItem)
                {
                    if (this.cart.merchant.id.toString() !== "<?php echo $merchantId; ?>" && this.cart.items.length)
                    {
                        return alert("Please complete your existing order first.");
                    }
                    
                    this.cart.items.push(foodItem);
                    this.cart.merchant.id = "<?php echo $merchantId; ?>";
                    
                    
                    $("#myModal-" + foodItem.food_id).modal("hide");
                    this.updateCartInLocalStorage();
                    window.cartVueApp.updateCartFromStorage();
                    
                    Snackbar.show({
                        pos  : "top-center",
                        text : "Item has been added to cart successfully"
                    });
                },
                onFoodItemQuantityDecrease : function(foodItem)
                {
                    foodItem.quantity = foodItem.quantity > 1 ? foodItem.quantity - 1 : foodItem.quantity;
                    this.updateCartInLocalStorage();
                },
                onFoodItemQuantityIncrease : function(foodItem)
                {
                    foodItem.quantity += 1;
                    this.updateCartInLocalStorage();
                },
                onFoodItemVarietySelect : function(variety, foodItem)
                {
                    foodItem.selectedVariety = variety;
                    this.updateCartInLocalStorage();
                },
                onFoodItemExtraSelect : function(extras, foodItem)
                {
                    foodItem.selectedExtras = extras;
                    this.updateCartInLocalStorage();
                },
                getItemPriceRange : function(item)
                {
                    if (!item.varietyDetails.length)
                    {
                        return "$" + item.price;
                    }
                    
                    var varietyPrices = item.varietyDetails.map(function(variety)
                    {
                        return Number(variety.price);
                    })
                    .sort();
                    
                    return varietyPrices.length > 1 ? "$" + varietyPrices.shift() + " - $" + varietyPrices.pop() : "$" + varietyPrices.shift();
                },
                onSearchFoodFormSubmit : function(event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    
                    if (!this.searchFood)
                    {
                        this.filteredCategories = this.categories;
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    var criteria = this.searchFood.toLowerCase();
                    var filtered = {};
                    var category = null;
                    
                    for (var categoryId in categories)
                    {
                        category = categories[categoryId];
                        
                        if (category.name && category.name.toLowerCase().includes(criteria))
                        {
                            filtered[categoryId] = category;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var items = category.items.slice().filter(function(item)
                            {
                                return item.food_name.toLowerCase().includes(criteria);
                            });
                            
                            if (items.length)
                            {
                                category = Object.assign({}, category, {
                                    items : items
                                });
                                
                                filtered[categoryId] = category;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    this.filteredCategories = filtered;
                }
            },
            created : function()
            {
                this.cart = window.localStorage.getItem("cart") ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("cart")) : this.cart;
                
                for (var category in this.categories)
                {
                    this.categories[category].items.forEach(function(item)
                    {
                        item.varietyDetails.sort(function(a, b)
                        {
                            var aPrice = Number(a.price);
                            var bPrice = Number(b.price);
                        
                            return aPrice > bPrice ? 1 : -1;
                        });
                        
                        item.extraDetails.sort(function(a, b)
                        {
                            var aPrice = Number(a.price);
                            var bPrice = Number(b.price);
                        
                            return aPrice > bPrice ? 1 : -1;
                        });
                    });
                }

                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $("#shippingMethod").on("change", function()
                    {
                         window.cartVueApp.checkoutForm.shipping_method = this.value;
                         window.localStorage.setItem("shippingMethod", this.value);
                    });
                    
                    var shippingMethod = window.localStorage.getItem("shippingMethod");
                    
                    if (shippingMethod && $("#shippingMethod option[value='" + shippingMethod + "']").length > 0)
                    {
                        $("#shippingMethod").val(shippingMethod);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
//         $(document).on('click', 'body *', function() {
//     $('.single-pro-menu .slicknav_nav.slicknav_hidden').removeClass('active');
// });
        $('.single-pro-menu .slicknav_menu  .slicknav_btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('.single-pro-menu .slicknav_nav.slicknav_hidden').toggleClass('active');
    });
     $('.dropdown.slicknav_parent .slicknav_item.slicknav_item.slicknav_row,.dropdown.slicknav_parent .slicknav_item.slicknav_item.slicknav_row .dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('.dropdown.slicknav_parent .dropdown-menu.slicknav_hidden,.dropdown.slicknav_parent .slicknav_item.slicknav_item.slicknav_row .dropdown-toggle').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $( ".popular-item-area .anchorMenuRow .popular-item " ).click(function(){
$(this).parents().find('.row.anchorMenuRow').css( {"position": "initial","z-inedx":"0" });
});
    }

    
    
</script>
<script>
    
    $('.dropdown.slicknav_parent .slicknav_item.slicknav_item.slicknav_row,.dropdown.slicknav_parent .slicknav_item.slicknav_item.slicknav_row .dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('.dropdown.slicknav_parent .dropdown-menu.slicknav_hidden,.dropdown.slicknav_parent .slicknav_item.slicknav_item.slicknav_row .dropdown-toggle').toggleClass('active');
    });
    
    $( ".popular-item-area .anchorMenuRow .popular-item " ).click(function(){
$(this).parents().find('.row.anchorMenuRow').css( {"position": "initial","z-inedx":"0" });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you have in your $categories?

Comment: These are Food Categories. Like Burger, Pizza. Food Categories a seller can create himself, as well as he can chose from the Categories which Admin has added. Admin added Categories are chosen by the seller while registration and then from his dashboard. Plus he can create his own categories from his dashboard as well. These categories then have food items in them

Comment: I mean, is the $categories a PHP array? Something like, $categories = ["Burger","Pizza"];

Comment: It is an array.

<?php 
              $menuCategories = [];
              
              $SellerMenu = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from food JOIN categories ON categories.id = food.category Where food.merchant_id = '$merchantId' group by categories.cat_name ORDER BY categories.id" );
              
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SellerMenu))
              {
                  $menuCategories[] = $row;
              }
              
              for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++):
          ?>

Comment: and this

<?php 
        $SellerMenu = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from food LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = food.category Where food.merchant_id = '$merchantId' GROUP BY categories.cat_name");
        
        $categories = [];
        
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SellerMenu))
        {
         $categories[$row["category"]] = [
          "name"  => $row["cat_name"],
          "items" => []
         ];
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error is in `var categories = JSON.parse('<?php echo stripslashes(json_encode($categories)); ?>');`

If your array in $categories is something like

`$categories1 = ["Burger", "Pizza", "Soft Drinks"];`

Then you do not need to use `JSON.parse`. You can just do like

```
var category1 = <?php echo(json_encode($categories1)); ?>;
```

[image]

If your array in $categories is something like

```
$categories2 = [
"cat1" =>[
    "id" =>1,
    "name" => "Burger"
    ],
"cat2" =>[
    "id" =>2,
    "name" => "Pizza"
    ],
"cat3" =>[
    "id" =>3,
    "name" => "Soft Drinks"
    ]];
```

Then you have to use `JSON.parse` like,

```
var category2 = JSON.parse('<?php echo(json_encode($categories2)); ?>');
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate. But none is working. Without JSON Parse, No error and no product gets displayed. 
With JSON.PARSE, same error. Here is my db 
https://ibb.co/2W97Qwk

Comment: Can you try console.log(<?php echo(json_encode($categories)); ?>) and check what prints in the browser console.

Comment: Thank you soo much Dula. You pointed out the issue. But i modified still some code for some random character that was generating

Comment: I fixed by this way

<script>

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var str = '<?php echo json_encode($categories);?>'
        
       var categories=str.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\t");
       
         categories = JSON.parse(categories);
        window.merchantDetailsVueApp = new Vue({
            el   : "#vueApp",
            data : function()

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by this. Though main credit goes to Dula.

```
<script>

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var str = '<?php echo json_encode($categories);?>'
        
       var categories=str.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\t");
       
         categories = JSON.parse(categories);
        window.merchantDetailsVueApp = new Vue({
            el   : "#vueApp",
            data : function()
```